# Why is metro bundler taking so long to load my app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, terminal, bundling-and-minification

My react native app takes 2 full minutes to load and I'm wondering what's the hold up. When it gets to 97.4% it just freezes for about two full minutes before going to 100%. How can I find out the reason for this delay?

```
>npm start -- --reset-cache

> crew_rn@0.0.1 start /Users/######/crew_rn
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start "--reset-cache"

Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/######/crew_rn/node_modules (9ms)
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/#####/crew_rn 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░ 97.4% (598/606)
```

Answer (score 12):

I see no one has answered my question and there is interest so I'll just share what I did.

In the package.json file - there were several dependencies. I took out all the dependencies and slowly put them back in until I identified the dependency which was causing the slowdown - and then I changed its version. This is the approach I took.